# Bootstrap5: How to Shrink Padding-Right on Element at Breakpoint?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have two columns in a row: one column holding an album image, and the other column holding some text describing the album. Above the medium breakpoint, the columns and the content within them are aligned perfectly. But when the screen is sized below the medium breakpoint, the column holding the album image expands to the right.

[image: Two columns in a row with first column's padding-right expanding]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-header py-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block column image-col">
        <img src="images/NirvanaNevermindalbumcover.jpg" class="rounded review-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-10 column text-col">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between album-header">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Nirvana - Nevermind</a></h5>
          <p>Avg. Rating: <span class="rating">8.6</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between user-header">
          <p class="text-muted">Reviewed by <a class="username" href="#">PunkyBruiser</a> on May 14, 2022</p>
          <p class="text-muted">User Review: <span class="added-rating">8</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried to use `pe-sm-1` and other similar size measurements from Bootstrap5 on the `<div class="col-2 ...">` but nothing has changed.
I've even tried putting a `d-flex justify-content-start` on the `row` but that didn't change anything either.